# Disable keyup/keydown formatting when using $.number() - jQuery Number Plugin by Custom D

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

How can I disable keyup/keydown formatting when using $.number()?

jQuery Number Plugin by Custom D https://github.com/customd/jquery-number

My code:

```
$( 'input' ).number( true, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was unbinding the 'keyup.format' and 'keydown.format' events from the element.

e.g

```
$( 'input' ).number( true, 2 ).unbind( 'keyup.format' ).unbind( 'keydown.format' );
```

Also, you could then manually format the number, now that the .number() plugin is instantiated against the input element.

e.g on a blur event

```
...
$( 'input' ).on( 'blur', function() {
    $(this).val( $(this).val() );
});
```